# Making Python code Pythonic

Tags: python

**How would you make the give code more Pythonic?**

I want to get Paths out of the sample like `/usr/local/sources/devel/algebra.py: def _alg(...)` without the character `:`.

**My code**

```
import os
FunctionPath = "/usr/local/sources/devel/sage-main/build/sage/"
cmd = "grep -R 'def ' %s | cut -d' ' -f1" % (FunctionPath)
cmd += ' &'
raw_path = os.system(cmd)
path = raw_path.replace(':', '')       // not working

print path
```

[edit]: The code *cannot be written pythonically* only with Built-in functions.

Comment: Who says that it can be written using only built-ins? Maybe the person meant that it can be done using only the Standard Python Library.

Comment: I agree with mikej.  It is extremely unpythonic to not use built-in libraries.  Batteries are included for a reason.

Comment: O(n^3)?? :-| I cannot see where do you get that.

Comment: btw what are you trying to achieve? t

Comment: Libraries or no libraries, punting out to the shell to do simple data processing tasks is definitely unpythonic, makes error handling hard, and includes many string-escaping pitfalls with potentially security-sensitive consequences. If you must do it, use the `subprocess` module to take care of most of the argument-escaping stuff. But there's certainly no need to resort to the shell for such trivial string slicing as this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
for line in open(FunctionPath):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('def '):
        print '%s: %s' % (FunctionPath, line.partition(':')[0])
```

And if you use [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module you can iterate over lines from multiple input streams very easily:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(paths):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('def '):
        print '%s: %s' % (fileinput.filename(), line.partition(':')[0])
```

BTW, if you don't give fileinput.input any path it will use sys.argv by default, so you can run your python script like this:

```
$ python script.py filepath1 filepath2 filepath3
```

fileinput will read the files for you.

if you really want to cover all cases, you shouldn't be using replace(':', '') because it is possible to have

```
def func(): #comment myfunc():
   pass
```

The following will give you the correct result:

```
>>> 'def func(): #comment myfunc():'.partition(':')[0]
'def func()'
```

Unless you want the comment as well.

Answer (score 1):

Literaly: "without the modules os, subprocess or Popen"

You can also use [commands](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html#commands.getoutput) module :P

Answer (score 1):

**Same with os.walk**

```
for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(function_path):
    for filename in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(path) as f:
             for line in f:
                 # Instead of grep
                 if 'def ' in line:
                       # Instead of cut
                       data = line.split(' ')[2]
                       print data.replace(":", '')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python mainly as a wrapper to sh, why not doing everything directly from the shell?

```
set SEARCH_PATH=/usr/local/sources/devel/sage-main/build/sage/
grep -R 'def ' $SEARCH_PATH | awk -F':' '{print $1 $2}'
```

Comment: I agree with you. It is easiest to use shell. The part could also be with `| cut -d' ' -f1 | sed s,:,,g`. Forgot `sed` when asking this question :)